# ASP.net MS-access like query not working using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, ms-access

All  like query doesnot work please help me,below are my code.

```
string Item_Name = txt_search.Text.Trim();
string Conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AjitConnectionString"].ToString();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Conn);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd;
cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [Item] where [Name] like '*'+inamer_Name+'*'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inamer_Name", Item_Name);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
grid_itemedit.DataSource = dt;
grid_itemedit.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [Item] where [Name] like '*" + inamer_Name + "*'", con);it also not working.please help me.

Comment: Please copy the answer correctly before you downvote

Comment: sorry i copied your exact ans yet its not working.

Comment: The comment  above mine is not an exact copy: you missed the wild card characters: `like '" + inamer_Name + "'"` in appose to `like '*" + inamer_Name + "*'"`. Note also the difference between .net quotes `"` and Access qoutes `'` in the command string

Comment: BTW, what is `inamer_Name`? it is not a `parameter` so `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inamer_Name", Item_Name);` should error. You also don't use a `SELECT` query as a command you execute in a `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`... so there are many things that could *not work* in the code.

Comment: cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [Item] where [Name] LIKE  '%'+@Item_MasalaName +'%'", con); its working ,thank you

Answer (score 1):

Wild card Character is part of the compared String.
[For example](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php):

> Like 'b*'
>   Result: all values that start with b

```
cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [Item] where [Name] like '%" + inamer_Name + "%'", con);
```

Comment: When using OleDb, you need different wildcards: `%` instead of `*`; and `_` instead of `?`